# I need a list with Send Keys for Blue Prism for Mainframe applications

Tags: blueprism

Please, if someone can help me with a list of Blue prism send keys for mainframe application.
I saw that some of them are different compare with what i already know. (for ex: in active accesibility mode u have to use command with {}, but in mainframe you have to use [] instead of {}.
Anyone knows where can i find a list with all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of each of the mainframe mnemonics is consolidated in the Mainframe Automation Guide on the Blue Prism portal, under the "Documents" tab. Unfortunately, I can't post the document or the link as it's clearly marked "Company Confidential".

*However,* the terminal mnemonics themselves are generally public information and are in the official documentation of the terminal emulators themselves.

The standard mnemonics for Attachmate emulators are listed in its [EHLLAPI documentation](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/whllapi.pdf) in Table B-1 (PDF page 114). The standard mnemonics for IBM emulators are listed in IBM's [Sendkeys Mnemonic Keywords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access11.htm) knowledge center article.